# Monotouch dialog - add and remove elements during runtime

Tags: multithreading, monotouch.dialog

I have an app in MonoTouch.Dialog where I try to use the ActivityElement.

My plan was to first show an activity element, then make my webservice call and when I got the response I would remove the activity element and instead add some new string elements.
This does not work. I am unable to remove or add elements once the view has been displayed.

How do I solve this?

```
rootElement = new RootElement ("Mobile Servicedesk"){
                (requestSection = new Section ("My requests"){
                    new ActivityElement()
                })
            };
            new Thread (() => {
                var incidents = IncidentProvider.LoadMyRequests ();
                requestSection.Elements.Clear ();
                foreach (var item in incidents) {
                    requestSection.Elements.Add (new StringElement(item.Name))
                }
            }
            ).Start ();
```

**EDIT:**

OK, now I got the updating part solved, at least in one part of my solution.

```
InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    ReloadData();
                });
```

ReloadData() works in my appDelegate view, but not in my subviews. I even tried to ensure that it is invokedd on the main thread but still no luck...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Got it!

Since I had a second RootElement I needed call ReloadData on that specific root... now it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used in my app' to do exactly what you want to do.

```
LoadingView loading;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((f) => {
    // runs UI stuff on main thread
    InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
        loading = new LoadingView();    
        loading.Show("Do something...");
    });

    // Methods that do whatever you wan, that runs on a different thread
    DoSomething();

    // runs UI stuff on main thread
    InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
        loading.Hide();
        new UIAlertView("Title", "Message", null, "Button", null).Show();
    }); 
});
```

Your main issue is, when you do `new Thread(...)`, you want to edit your UI, that is not possible if this is out the main thread.

In my example, the `DoSomething()` method, you can call your webservice, stock your data and then, in an `InvokeMainThread` create your Root the way you show.